# CryptographyDeprecationWarning with snowflake.connector.connect

Tags: cryptography, pyopenssl, snowflake-connector

When I run `snowflake.connector.connect(**credentials['MY_DATABASE'])`, I get the following warning:

> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: This version of cryptography contains a temporary pyOpenSSL fallback path. Upgrade pyOpenSSL now.
> warnings.warn(

I have updated pyOpenSSL to its latest version. These are the versions I've installed:

[image]

I am not sure what updates I need to make to avoid getting this warning. I'd appreciate your help.